# meteor How can I login without password

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform, rocket.chat

The situation is that I have a Meteor app, and now have an another app wanna login to my app, and it provided a `sessionId` to me, I will use the Id to request username, if responsed the username in my MongoDB, I should let it login, but I don't know how can I bypass password?

And I use Rocket.Chat, the app used inner company, so, don't worry security, Thank you!

Comment: Please reformulate your question in a clear way.

Comment: You question is not really clear

Comment: Does it help ? https://github.com/lorensr/login-links/

Comment: Thanks, this is useful

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the meteor login service for Rocket.Chat, https://atmospherejs.com/rocketchat/accounts-rocketchat